# How can I reactively create or delete object property using mutations in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an objects array in state, and I want to add or delete or redact property to one of objects using mutation:

```
state: {
    persons: [
        {
            photo: "/src/assets/person1.jpg",
            name: "Jacky Nikson",
            phoneNumber: "+1234567890"
        },
        {
            photo: "/src/assets/person2.jpg",
            name: "Jacky Nikson",
            phoneNumber: "+1236567220"
        },
        {
            photo: "/src/assets/person3.jpg",
            name: "Jacky Nikson",
            phoneNumber: "+1224567850"
        }
    ]
},

mutations: {
    removeParam(state, payload){
        state.$delete(state.persons[payload.index], payload.key);
    },
    addParam(state, payload){            
        state.$set(state.persons[payload.index], payload.key, payload.value);            
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I can't use Vue methods like $delete or $set from Vuex, so how can I do that kind of thing not from component, but from Vuex mutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
Vue.set( target, propertyName/index, value )
Vue.delete( target, propertyName/index )
```

but don't forget to import Vue in your file :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

Comment: Thank you very much)